# Creation of nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my app I have projects which has tickets. I want to be able to show a ticket in the following way:

```
/projects/43/tickets
```

This route works but results in showing all tickets, not only tickets that belongs to the project. What do I need to change?

**Routes:**

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tickets do
    collection do
      get "manage"
    end 
  end
end
```

**Models:**

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  ...
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end
```

A ticket is connected to a project in the following way:

```
Tickets (table)
    project_id
    ...the rest of the fields...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controller logic, not route logic. In `tickets_controller.rb`

```
def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @tickets = @project.tickets
end
```

Now, `@tickets` will contain all tickets for the current project.